# how to add multiple checkmarks to an li element

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox which i turned into a checkmark.It gets appended into multiple li statements,the problem i am having is that each li statement ends up with the same id element which results in only one element been checked.
i have attached a working jsfiddle as follows
https://jsfiddle.net/25er3cx9/1/

i tried to change the id to a class as follows:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none" id="cb"  ><label for="cb" class="checkmark"></label></span> // this is how it is currently
```

what i tried

```
<span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none cb" ><label for="cb" class="checkmark"></label></span> // when i tried this it stops working,doesnt allow me to tick the checkmark
```

the above code gets added to my  elements
as follows

```
var list = $('<ul></ul>');
$.each(this.Markets, function () {
   list.append('<li style="padding-left:28px"><a class="internal" data- data-nodeid = "' + this.NodeId + '"><span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none" id="cb" ><label for="cb" class="checkmark"></label></span>' + this.Name + '</a></li>');});
```

so each li statement that comes in gets appended with the above which results in all of the elments having the same id.
is there a way i can set it without having it use the same id multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what u accurately wanna approach.
First,i think  u should not use "display:none" in class , maybe in style is much correct.like style="display:none",And if u whant to check it one by one  you should use different id , the id might base on backend variable.

### Hope this help u .

try like this ?
use Node Id to recognize different checkbox.

```
var list = $('<ul></ul>');
$.each(this.Markets, function() {
    list.append('<li style="padding-left:28px"><a class="internal" data- data-nodeid = "' + this.NodeId + '"><span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none" id="cb'+this.NodeId+'" ><label for="cb" class="checkmark"></label></span>' + this.Name + '</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: Hi,yes i am not sure how to change the ID as it is appended,i have updated my code,hope that makes better sense

Comment: Ah!! thanks you so much i didnt even realise that,and it was bugging me the whole day

Comment: the only thing i changed from above was that i also added it to the label for="cb'+this.NodeId+'"

Comment: Great job , have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

you have to change 'id' and 'for' attribute in label tag as well :

```
<span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none" id="cb1"  ><label for="cb1" class="checkmark"></label></span>
<span><input type="checkbox" class="display:none" id="cb2"  ><label for="cb2" class="checkmark"></label></span>
```